# Detecting if NFC is active or passive in Android

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to write an application that logs NFC events. While detecting whether NFC is enabled/disabled is easy, I can't find a straightforward way to detect when NFC is reading/pushing data (active) and when that is finished (back to passive). The data, or message content is not the point of interest, i.e. I don't care what it is.

So, is there a way to detect whether NFC chip in an Android device has started or finished data transfer?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API that would permit you to trace these events on stock Android.

- If you have the ability to create your customized Android system, you could add such tracing functionality to the NFC system service (more specifically to those parts of the service that are used to interface tags and that provide LLCP/Beam functionality).
- If you have access to the system log, you could try to evaluate the NFC related log messages in order to determine when data is actively transferred over NFC. However, specifically with regard to apps accessing tags, there is not a lot of useful system log messages to determine when communication actually takes place. Moreover, some device manufacturers make their devices be less verbose in their system log.